# Javascript event.preventDefault() not working on modal

Tags: javascript, angular, modal-dialog, simplemodal

I am working in Angular to implement accessibility and adding (keyup.space) events on clickable elements.
Space press has a default behavior that moves the scrollbar, which I don't want
to happen. I managed to skip it in the main page by using event.preventDefault(), but when I press space in a button in the modal
the behavior is present although I use event.preventDefault().

Is there any way to stop the default behavior of moving the scrollbar when I press space in an element in the modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `(keyup.space)="$event.preventDefault();onClickMethod()"` event. I fixed it by using `(keydown.space)=="$event.preventDefault();onClickMethod()"`

Answer (score 0):

If it is vanilla js, it should work as expected.

https://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/xpd832mk/

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode === 32) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```